# What parameters need to be put in the code in order to execute correctly the requests.post function?

Tags: python, python-requests, python-requests-html

What parameters need to be put in regards to this site (www.pyszne.pl) so that the requests function can be executed properly? I need to have a url which leads to the restaurants available under a specific postcode.

here is my code:

```
import requests

payload = {'myvaluestring':'30-529'}
r = requests.post('https://www.pyszne.pl', data=payload)

print(r.url)
```

I'm only receiving the same main page url https://www.pyszne.pl/

Comment: Would you know how to open the page you want from a browser? Why do you think you need to post `{'myvaluestring':'30-529'}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a `GET` situation, not `POST`. Try this:

```py
In [1]: import requests                                                                                                                                                                                            

In [2]: r = requests.get("https://www.pyszne.pl/30-529")                                                                                                                                                           

In [3]: r.url                                                                                                                                                                                                      
Out[3]: 'https://www.pyszne.pl/restauracja-krakow-krakow-podgorze-30-529'
```

I recommend you to do a search on web *"what's the difference of HTTP POST and GET"*.